# docker stack: is it possible to set it to automatically refresh containers after some maximum lifetime?

Tags: docker, docker-compose, docker-stack

I would like containers in one of my docker stack services to automatically be refreshed every hour.

I start with 3 instances, and every hour I would like them to be replaced with new instances one at a time, serially.

Is there a way to achieve this with `docker-compose`? Or alternatively with a `cron` job?

Thanks!

Comment: Why do you want this?

Comment: Even tho the process running inside my docker container has its own failsafe mechanisms (it's `gunicorn`, and I set it up to rotate worker after a maximum number of connections, and so on), and my docker container has a memory usage cap (that is not really reaching anyway), too often one such container will not be very responsive. Having a max lifetime is the easiest way to fix the issue and there is no downtime as I run these containers with redundancy anyway.

Comment: `too often one such container will not be very responsive` I would start by fixing that.

Comment: I have tried and invested enough time in it, so next is the nuclear solution, hence this question :)